# Finding necessary sample size for a two-way fixed effects model (preferably in stata)

Tags: sample-size, stata, simulation, statistical-power

I want to do a bit of research that necessitates the use of a generalized difference-in-difference design with multiple fixed effects. Essentially, I will use a two-way fixed effects model with controls for institution and time.

However, accessing data is expensive. So, before I pay to buy this data, I want to know that I have a solid chance of identifying effects (if they exist or estimating a precise zero.

I know how many instances of treatment I will observe. I know how many institutions I will have in my control group. I know how many people work in each treated institution and I can easily find how many people are at the control institutions (but we can assume that both are quite large).

I want to learn about the impact of an institution-level treatment on individual-level outcomes for people working at treated institutions.

How can I determine a necessary sample size to detect effects of various sizes given a certain power level and a range of alpha values? I prefer to do this in Stata, if possible.

Please let me know if I need to provide more detail or provide a detailed example etc.